# Would upgrading from .net 2.0 to 4.0 give a performance increase?

Tags: .net, performance, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

We have finally put our giant VB.net 2.0 Web Application into a code freeze exclusively so we can put some performance enhancements into it.

I was wondering if it would be worth it to upgrade the .Net version to increase the application's performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be worthwhile to upgrade, but not due to automatic improvements.

It will be worthwhile to upgrade because you'll have more options on how to fix the performance problems.

It will also be worthwhile to upgrade because .NET 2.0 is **six years old**! Don't *ever* stay in the past unless you have to, or you'll eventually wind up having to explain why you're using decade-old technology.

Comment: Good point, but they are in code freeze, so perhaps major overhauls using TPL, for example, not a great idea.

Comment: @chiba: I note that the code freeze is for the purpose of improving performance. I took that to mean there will be no code changes except for performance changes.

Comment: Definitely, I was thinking more of the wrecking ball angle.

Comment: @John - You are correct the purpose of this freeze is purely for performance. I'll update the question.

Comment: @chiba: what wrecking ball? .NET 2.0 to 4.0 is almost a no-brainer. They would then get to use the newer features only where needed to improve performance.

Comment: @John I'm thinking more about introducing a load of new (perhaps not very well understood) technology into a project at code freeze to solve performance problems that are perhaps not well understood. Perhaps I'm being cynical. What technologies in .Net 4.0 do you think would be especially useful in .Net for a web application i.e. something you couldn't have done before?

Comment: @chiba: .NET 4.0 isn't "new" any more, and it's being used by many millions of people. TPL, in particular, might be helpful, as it can greatly simplify multithreading - to the extent that you can now use threading where you wouldn't previously have dared to do so. For another, if they use web services internally, then moving to WCF permits them to use binary over TCP/IP instead of SOAP. LINQ to XML and LINQ to Objects can make several other problems much easier to fix. The list goes on. .NET 4.0 to .NET 2.0 is a big leap in functionality.

Comment: @chiba: of course you should profile first, so that you're fixing the right problem.

Comment: @John I have been using .Net 4.0 since it came out, along with the millions of other people you mention. I am assuming it's new to them. You mention some technologies that make things easier, agreed, but not necessarily perform faster, which is my point...

Comment: @chiba: I'm saying that, for instance, one might have used `System.Threading.Thread` to try to improve performance, but it's too hard to get that right. Using TPL is not only easier, it's much easier to get it right. So, to the extent that multi-threading actually would help, in .NET 4.0, it's now practical. Similarly with the use of various LINQ's to turn inefficient algorithms which perhaps used looping into faster ones using sets. Having more options is better.

Comment: @John I get you on TPL, I really do, I would never want to go back. I would still be wary about introducing .Net 4.0 if I wasn't familiar with the performance characteristics of it or my application. You can still make things slower using TPL and Linq, etc. They are both wonderful technologies, don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Impossible to say. You would have to design some repeatable performance tests, and then A->B them against your application running on each .Net version. For instance, your application's performance could be influenced by IO, or memory constraints. A .Net upgrade is unlikely to help with this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of taking a huge shot in the dark (building w/ 4.0) to try and increase performance you should [run a profiler](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20code%20profiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) against your code base to identify performance bottle necks. You might upgrade anyway but if you do get a performance boost it would most likely be negligible. Profiling and fixing bottle necks regardless of version will be the best way to proceed.

Btw, if you do go with 4.0 and VS 2010 you get a [profiler built into the IDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2009/06/10/write-faster-code-with-vs-2010-profiler.aspx).